# Why isn't this AJAX call executing properly?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm building a site that offers a discount based upon a promo code that the user has the option to enter. It's necessary for me to validate that the code exists in our database before processing a new signup. Here's the AJAX call I'm using for validation:

```
if (promo_code) {
    var returned = true;
    $.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "/ajax/validate_promo_code.php",
        data:    {promo_code: promo_code},
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == 0) {
                $('#blank_dialog_popup').html('<span class="message_text_big">Sorry, that promo code is not valid.</span>').addClass('message_warning').css('display', 'block').css('z-index', '1003');
                setTimeout(returnMessageBackground, 3000);
                $('#promo_code').focus();
                returned = false;
            }
        }
    });
    if (returned != true) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's the entire PHP file I use for validation.

```
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    $db = new Database();
    $promo_code = filter_var(intval($_POST['promo_code']), FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING);
    $check_query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE promo_code = '$promo_code'";
    $db->query($check_query);
    if ($db->num_rows != 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
?>
```

The success field won't execute, even if I comment out every line of code from the PHP file except for "return 0;" and get rid of the "data:" line in the AJAX call, which makes me think there's something dreadfully wrong with my code, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, I hope nobody ever uses the following promo code: `1\'; DELETE FROM users;` please read up on protecting your application from MySQL injection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 3):

`return` does not cause a PHP program to write output. You need [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) or [`print`](http://php.net/print) for that.

---

Also, [you are trying to read the value of your JS `returned` variable before you set it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: Thanks! So, ignoring the asynchronous issue, changing the return statement in the PHP file to echo or print would give me what I needed?

Answer (score 1):

First of all as @Quentin stated you need to use echo or print.

Second:

AJAX request as aysnc. That means the code is not executed in order but the `success()` function is called later on (After the Server responded). What I mean with that is that this part

```
if (returned != true) {
    return false;
}
```

Will never be executed since you are changing the value of `returned` in the `success()` method which is only executed async.

Here is an example fiddle how to manipulate UI stuff async: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/663873/

Comment: Gotcha. I see now that this is a really common problem asked by a lot of people who don't understand async yet. Any recommendations for a workaround? The code is now working properly other than the return statement, and I'm having a hard time understanding the link Quentin sent.

Answer (score 0):

So there were a few problems with this code that I figured out with a lot of research. The main one was that I needed to use "async: false" to make the AJAX call asynchronous. I had a hard time understanding the solutions in @Quentin's link. I've changed some things below to make it a little cleaner and clearer, but this is the final, working version of the function.

```
// Validate promo code, if present.
if (promo_code) {
    var flag = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "/ajax/validate_promo_code.php",
        data:    {promo_code: promo_code},
        async:   false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 0) {
                $('#blank_dialog_popup').html('<span class="message_text_big">Sorry, that promo code is not valid.</span>').addClass('message_warning').css('display', 'block').css('z-index', '1003');
                setTimeout(returnMessageBackground, 3000);
                $('#promo_code').focus();
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    if (flag == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That was the main issue, but I also had some errors in my PHP code. First, I needed to include the code that creates the Database class. Second, I had to sanitize my string input more effectively. Third, my SQL query did not fetch every row that contains the promo code as I intended. And finally, I didn't need the return statement to have any logic in it. Here's the final version.

```
require_once('../smarty/Authenticate.inc.php');

$db = new Database();
$promo_code = StringInputCleaner($_POST['promo_code']);
$check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE promo_code = '$promo_code'";
$db->query($check_query);
$return = $db->num_rows;

echo $return;

function StringInputCleaner($data) {
    //remove space before and after
    $data = trim($data); 
    //remove slashes
    $data = stripslashes($data); 
    $data = (filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    return $data;
}
```

Hopefully this helps somebody!

Comment: using `async: false` is reaaaaly bad practice. But in your case i unterstand you using this since it helps to you to progress. Never the less you should try to fix your javascript code to be able to handle async.

Comment: Here is an example fiddle how to manipulate UI stuff async: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/663873/

Comment: This is seriously above and beyond, my friend. Thank you!